# How to call an abstract method from a Class parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

## Aim

Have a function `Book`, which takes one of three Letter classes as argument `myClass` and then calls 'genericMethod()' from the abstract class which `Letter*()` has inherited.

## Issue

If I try `Book(LetterA()).read()` I get the following error:

`Type mismatch. Required: Class<SampleClassArguments.Alphabet> Found: SampleClassArguments.LetterA`

Does Kotlin have any way to achieve this result?

## Code

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun readBookTest() {
        Book(LetterA()).read() /*<--error here*/
    }

    class Book(val myClass: Class<Alphabet>) {
        fun read() {
            val letterClass = myClass.getConstructor().newInstance()
            letterClass.genericMethod(myClass.name)
        }
    }
    
    class LetterA(): Alphabet()
    class LetterB(): Alphabet()
    class LetterC(): Alphabet()

    abstract class Alphabet {
        fun genericMethod(className: String) {
            println("The class is: $className")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the Class type as covariant with the `out` keyword so any of the child classes is an acceptable argument:

```
class Book(val myClass: Class<out Alphabet>)
```

And when you use it, you need to pass the actual Class, not an instance of the class. You can get the Class by calling `::class.java` on the name of the class:

```
@Test
fun readBookTest() {
    Book(LetterA::class.java).read()
}
```